# how to add and deleting the record for grid

Tags: angular, typescript

```
actionBegin(args) {
    debugger
    if (args.requestType == 'save') {
        args.Cancel = true;
        if (args.data.id == undefined || args.data.id == null) {
            var lastId = 1;
            if (this.subContractorGridData != null && this.subContractorGridData.length > 0) {
                lastId = this.subContractorGridData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[this.subContractorGridData.length - 1].id;
                lastId++;
            }
            if (this.procuredData != null && this.procuredData.length > 0) {
                lastId = this.procuredData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[this.procuredData.length - 1].id;
                lastId++;
            }
            if (this.subContProgProgressData != null && this.subContProgProgressData.length > 0) {
                lastId = this.subContProgProgressData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[this.subContProgProgressData.length - 1].id;
                lastId++;
            }
            if (this.subContFinalEstimateData != null && this.subContFinalEstimateData.length > 0) {
                lastId = this.subContFinalEstimateData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[this.subContFinalEstimateData.length - 1].id;
                lastId++;
            }
            if (this.subContValuationData != null && this.subContValuationData.length > 0) {
                lastId = this.subContValuationData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)[this.subContValuationData.length - 1].id;
                lastId++;
            }
            args.data.id = lastId;
            args.data.projectId = this.projectId;
            args.data.projectExReviewDetailId = this.projectExReviewDetailId;
            // this.frmReviewSubContract.get('Value').setValue('120');
            // this.frmReviewSubContract.get('SubContinvOrApp').setValue('select');
            // this.frmReviewSubContract.get('Status').setValue('select');
            this.notify.success(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
        }
        else {
            var idx = this.subContractorGridData.findIndex(x => x.id == args.data.id);
            this.subContractorGridData.splice(idx, 1, args.data);
            var idx = this.procuredData.findIndex(x => x.id == args.data.id);
            this.procuredData.splice(idx, 1, args.data);
            var idx = this.subContProgProgressData.findIndex(x => x.id == args.data.id);
            this.subContProgProgressData.splice(idx, 1, args.data);
            var idx = this.subContFinalEstimateData.findIndex(x => x.id == args.data.id);
            this.subContFinalEstimateData.splice(idx, 1, args.data);
            var idx = this.subContValuationData.findIndex(x => x.id == args.data.id);
            this.subContValuationData.splice(idx, 1, args.data);
            this.notify.success(this.l('Updated successfully'));
        }
        // this.subContractorGridData.push(args.data);
        this.grid.refresh();
        this.subContractGridValue.emit(this.subContractorGridData);
        this.subProcuredGridValue.emit(this.procuredData);
        this.subContProgProgressValue.emit(this.subContProgProgressData);
        this.subContFinalEstimateValue.emit(this.subContFinalEstimateData);
        this.subconValuationValue.emit(this.subContValuationData);
        this.procuredData=[];

    }
    if (args.requestType === 'delete') {
        args.cancel = true;
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.message.confirm('', this.l('AreYouSure'), (isConfirmed) => {
                if (!isConfirmed) {
                    resolve(false);
                    return;
                }
                else resolve(true);
            });
        }).then(val => {
            if (val) {
                args.data.forEach(x => {
                    this.deleteSubContractor(x.id);    
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my code and i am trying to save the grid data in json format so here is problem facing how they know for this is a data for the particular grid and they want to delete the data for particular grid now what happed with me if i am adding the data in grid this data also adding the other grid if i am deleting the data then all grid data are deleting what i do for that if you have any suggestion please suggest me

I am trying to save the data in json formate it's save but problem is the if i am deleted the data for particular grid but all grid data are deleted and same happend this things while i am adding any data please suggest me how to solve this problem